# PostGIS only works with root user

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I have a database and am trying to use PostGis with it.
When I run:

```
$ psql -h localhost -d $APP_DB_NAME -U $APP_DB_USER
# SELECT PostGIS_version();
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT PostGIS_version();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

But when I enter the database as root:

```
$ sudo su postgres -c psql $APP_DB_NAME
# SELECT PostGIS_version();
```

It runs fine:

```
            postgis_version
---------------------------------------
 2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
(1 row)
```

I am installing the PostGis extension as the root user, since my user doesn't have super_user access.

```
$ su - postgres -c psql $APP_DB_NAME
# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: `sudo su postgres -c psql` is just a slow and annoying way to write `sudo -u postgres psql`. Anyway, you're not entering the database as "root", but as the `postgres` superuser. Are you totally sure you're connecting to the *same database* in both cases? `SHOW current_database;` in each session.

Comment: That command gave me the following error: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "current_database". But I think you are right, they are different databases, since they have different tables. Isn't localhost the default host?

Comment: Depends - do you have the PGPORT or PGHOST env vars set in either session? Also I should have said `SELECT current_database();` sorry

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the owner of the schema in which postgis is installed is not the user you're logging in as, but rather the "root" user (which is postgres).

```
$ psql postgres
postgres=# \dn
    List of schemas
    Name        |  Owner
--------------------+----------
public             | postgres
pg_catalog         | postgres
my_data            | someuser
```

When connecting as postgres, postgis will work in this case, but if you connect as any other user, it will fail, and say it's not there, even though if you try to `create extension postgis` it will say it's installed already.

To correct this, make sure all the schemas are owned by the user you're actually connecting as:

```
ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO my_user;
```